# Random LED turning on and off in VHDL

Tags: random, vhdl, led

I want to implement a random-number game on BASYS2. In this game there would be five LEDs chosen out of which one would turn on at random for a second or two (this time can be changed to increase or decrease the difficulty level of the game). Then the user is required to respond to this LED event by pressing the switch button behind it within the time that it is on. If he or she is able to do so successfully a point would be scored and it would be showed on the Seven Segment Display. If he or she fails no point would be scored. There would be 9 such events after which the game can be replayed.

```
Now following is my code (only for the random LED turning on). However, I am unable to fix it. Please somebody help. The FPGA I am using is BASYS2 SPARTAN 3E-100.
```

Thanks in advance to everyone.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_unsigned.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_arith.ALL;

entity random_number is
generic ( width : integer :=  4 ); 
port (
clk : in std_logic;
reset : in std_logic;
random_num : out std_logic_vector (width-1 downto 0)   --output vector            
);
end random_number;

architecture Behavioral of random_number is
signal q: std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
signal divided_clock: std_logic;
begin
process(clk, reset)
begin
if (reset = '1')then 
q <= X"000000";
elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then
q <= q + 1;
end if;
end process;
divided_clock <= q(22);


process (divided_clock)
variable rand_temp : std_logic_vector(width-1 downto 0):=("1000");
variable temp : std_logic := '0';
begin
if(rising_edge(divided_clock)) then
temp := rand_temp(width-1) xor rand_temp(width-2);
rand_temp(width-1 downto 1) := rand_temp(width-2 downto 0);
rand_temp(0) := temp;
end if;
random_num <= rand_temp;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the second process should even run with the main clk and the devided clock should be an enable.

```
signal divided_enable: std_logic;
process(clk, reset)
begin
if (reset = '1')then 
  q <= X"000000";
elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then
  q <= q + 1;
end if;
if (q(22) = '1') then
  --short pulse wenn q bit 22 is high
  divided_enable <= '1';
  q <= (others => '0');
end if;
end process;


process (clk)
variable rand_temp : std_logic_vector(width-1 downto 0):=("1000");
variable temp : std_logic := '0';
begin
if(rising_edge(clk)) then
  if(divided_enable = '1') then
    temp := rand_temp(width-1) xor rand_temp(width-2);
    rand_temp(width-1 downto 1) := rand_temp(width-2 downto 0);
    rand_temp(0) := temp;
   end if;
 end if;
random_num <= rand_temp;
end process;
```

I don't know if this will fix all your problems. Please discribe compiler errors or errors in the behavior.

Comment: it's very kind of you. The code you modified worked without any errors. I would keep asking some questions time and again because I have a project to submit at the end of the current semester. See you then.

Comment: @user3518317, if the solution works for you maybe you could mark the answer as accepted? That's standard practice here and a nice way to show your gratitude  :)